# Rviz xyz plane view

Tags: ros, rviz, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, when I connected my Hokuyo laser to my computer and walked through the tutorials on [How to use Hokuyo Laser Scanners with the hokuyo_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode) it changed Rviz to only view the XY plane. I feel like I'm just forgetting to change something very obvious but how do I change the plane view back to XYZ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11403/rviz-xyz-plane-view/) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a drop-down box in the "Views" panel that contains three choices: TopDownOrtho, Orbit, and FPS. If you select "Oribit", you'll be able to rotate in the XYZ planes.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4